# Problem with changing login screen

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, login-screen

I tried several time to change my log in screen by using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. I choose `lightdm` from here. But my log in screen is unchanged and look like below.[image: Log in screen]

How can I change this and back to my default unity log in screen??

Answer (score 0):

If the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` not work, edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf file with your favorite editor:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Make sure the greeter-session is the unity-greeter, then restart.

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

If the problem continue then give a try to this command:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" install --reinstall lightdm
```

Comment: I have tried both of your solution. And when I restarted my PC its showing an [error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5D5hCeTJZ0XVXhFVzB6LVo3cXc/edit?usp=sharing) `The system is running in low graphics mode`. Then I choose **low graphics mode** and my log in screen appear like [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5D5hCeTJZ0XUHRVV3U3NlZnTjA/edit?usp=sharing). And icons in dash become bigger in unity.

Comment: This is a problem in your graphics check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Comment: I have no graphics card in my PC. And this is appearing after trying your method.

Comment: `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf` then
`sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: First command showing `rm: cannot remove `/etc/X11/xorg.conf': No such file or directory`

Comment: what is the output of `ls /etc/X11`

Comment: This the [output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5D5hCeTJZ0XRGVhb2FvUmNmSTg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: please list here

Comment: `app-defaults             rgb.txt             Xreset      Xsession.options
cursors                  X                   Xreset.d    Xwrapper.config
default-display-manager  xinit               Xresources
fonts                    xkb                 Xsession
fs                       xorg.conf.failsafe  Xsession.d`

Comment: `sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe /etc/X11/xorg.conf` then reboot

Comment: Nothing improved. Same problem as before.

Comment: What is your graphic?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13541/discussion-between-hadi-and-scotia)